# Pandas unstack documentation

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to understand the [last example in the pandas docs for unstack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

```
>>> index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('one', 'a'), ('one', 'b'),('two', 'a'), ('two', 'b')])
>>> s = pd.Series(np.arange(1.0, 5.0), index=index)
>>> s
one  a   1.0
     b   2.0
two  a   3.0
     b   4.0
```

The way I explain `unstack` is that it pulls levels out of a hierarchical index and places them above as columns.  The parameter eg. -1, 0  represents which level of the hierarchical index it moves to the columns' side.

So it makes sense in the two examples how `s.unstack(0)` and `s.unstack(-1)` convert levels of the index to columns.

What I don't follow is the last example where we have two rows, two columns.

```
df = df.unstack(level=0)
df
   one  two
a  1.0  3.0
b  2.0  4.0
```

When I apply `df.unstack()` it brings the columns back down as members of the hierarchical index.

```
df.unstack()
one  a    1.0
     b    2.0
two  a    3.0
     b    4.0
dtype: float64
```

I don't understand why that's the behavior, and what the default is.  I suppose it is somehow because neither index nor columns started out as hierarchical indexes, but I really can't conclude.  Feel like there is something more that I'm not groking about this.

Comment: default of unstack is (-1), in your case is level=1